# i want to find the negative and positive of the same value in column and delete it

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

I have a data of transaction and there's refunds in it and i want to select it and delete it, you can say my data look like this :

```py
product key     mtligne_ttc      partner_id     date
1001            14.50            10024          20-12-2018
1001            14.50            10024          20-12-2018 
1002            21.30            22444          10-10-2018
1003            11.10            516            05-10-2018
1002           -21.30            22444          23-10-2018
1005            5.50             1800           01-09-2018
1006            8.30             4221           01-09-2018
1003           -11.10            516            06-10-2018
1003            11.10            516            09-10-2018
```

i found this code online but it doesn't work properly because it check if the value has a negative value and he added to the new one

```py
def refunded(data):
    return data[data["mtligne_ttc"].isin(-data["mtligne_ttc"])]
dataset1 = dataset.groupby("partner_id").apply(refunded).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

so the output would be like :

```py
product key     mtligne_ttc      partner_id     date
1002            21.30            22444          10-10-2018
1003            11.10            516            05-10-2018
1002           -21.30            22444          23-10-2018
1003           -11.10            516            06-10-2018
1003            11.10            516            09-10-2018
```

there's like a 11.10 added which is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. May I ask if there are more than 2 same values with different signs, for example `11.10`, do you only need two or show all?

Comment: i have clients make many transactions and in those transaction there's who make a refund. i tried to group by product key and partner_id then check if the sum is equal to 0 then delete but in this case it won't work for example here there's 11.10 and -11.10 and 11.10 so the sum won't be zero

Comment: I see, so it's just two values based on the `mtligne_ttc ` and `partner_id`?

Comment: yh you can say so

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 hours looking to the problem and when i gave up i tried to post here but the funny thing 22 min later i solved it.
My solution was there's was the quantity columns in the dataset. and if someone wants to make a refund he'll refund the same quantity. so here's my solution, i grouped first the partner_id(client id) and default_code(product key) and qte(quantity) why because the partner_id(client id) and default_code are unique and quantity because it indicate the refund so if the sum equal to 0 i select it:

```py
dataset1 = dataset[dataset.groupby(['partner_id','default_code','qte'])['mtligne_ttc'].transform('sum').eq(0)]
```